# Twiiter like real time response using PHP

Tags: php, twitter, real-time, updates

Can anyone explain how does the real time response works in Twitter ? 
Like when u search in twitter while viewing the result u get real-time updates saying
"7 more people tweeted" .
I have noticed there is no AJAX call being made.
Can someone tell me how this works and is it possible to implement such a thing using PHP ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firebug shows that it is making asynchronous calls to the server:

http://integratedsearch.twitter.com/search.html?_=1262187845554&q=new+year&since_id=7199106684&refresh=true&callback=processSummizeRefresh

Note the variables:

- q: "new year"
- since_id: 7199106684
- refresh: true
- callback processSummizeRefresh

All it's doing is looking for any matches to the `q` variable whose ID is greater than `since_id` and returning a count. If you load the results, by clicking "123 new tweets," the `since_id` will be updated to reflect the new latest ID value.

Comment: It has to query the server its understood. How does it do it without making any AJAX calls ?

Comment: It IS making ajax a calls. I pulled this information out of firebug.

Comment: Okay finally found that it does make AJAX calls. Can you give me a reason why the AJAX call made, does not get logged into the console tab of firebug. Coz most of the applications I seen, all the AJAX calls get logged into the console tab of firebug, in twitters case it isnt so?

Comment: If you open firebug after you've already loaded the page, I think it may not capture future asynchronous traffic. Try going to the page with firebug opened, then refresh the page.

Answer (score 2):

It's all about comet, as mentioned by Zack. Implementations in PHP are tricky; Facebook uses Erlang.

If you want to get started with PHP without the hassle of setting up your own server, check out [WebSync On-Demand](http://www.frozenmountain.com/websync).

Answer (score 1):

It's probably using long polling. See [comet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comet_(programming)).